# I want to find a particular string in a dataframe and after finding the string, I want to exclude that particular row from the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on financial statements in reports and I need to exclude the dates, currency, and units from the dataframe.

I have tried to exclude the rows by giving the column and the string.

```
df = df[~df['A'].isin(['As of December 31, 2018'])]
```

I am not sure in which column this particular string will appear, so I want to find `'As of December 31, 2018'` which is unique and find it in dataframe and once it's found I want to exclude that particular row from the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all fields to find that any of them contains your specified string using `any()` function and apply it to all rows of dataframe with pandas `apply()` function:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data_json = [
    {
    'field_1': 'As of December 31, 2018',
    'field_2': '1',
    'field_3': '2'
},
{
    'field_1': '3',
    'field_2': '4',
    'field_3': '5'

},
{
    'field_1': '6',
    'field_2': 'As of December 31, 2018',
    'field_3': '7'

},
{
    'field_1': '8',
    'field_2': '9',
    'field_3': '10'
},
{
    'field_1': '11',
    'field_2': '12',
    'field_3': 'As of December 31, 2018'   
}]

data = pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_json))
print(data)
```

Output is:

```
                   field_1                  field_2                  field_3
0  As of December 31, 2018                        1                        2
1                        3                        4                        5
2                        6  As of December 31, 2018                        7
3                        8                        9                       10
4                       11                       12  As of December 31, 2018
```

After that, using `apply()` + `any()`:

```
data_filtered = data[~data.apply(lambda x: any([True for elem in x if elem == 'As of December 31, 2018']), axis=1)]
print(data_filtered)
```

Output is:

```
  field_1 field_2 field_3
1       3       4       5
3       8       9      10
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to delete rows based on multiple values, you can modify your code that way:

```
data_filtered = data[~data.apply(lambda x: any([True for elem in x if elem in ['As of December 31, 2018', 'As of March 31, 2018']]), axis=1)]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, what if we want to delete more than 1 row with different strings, in this case how will we code it, for ex. 'As of March 31, 2018' ,'As of December 31, 2018' in different rows which i want to delete

Comment: newdf_filtered = df[~df.apply(lambda x: any([True for elem in x if elem == 'As of December 31, 2018']), axis=1)]
newdf1_filtered = newdf_filtered[~newdf_filtered.apply(lambda x: any([True for elem in x if elem == 'Assets']), axis=1)]
print (newdf1_filtered)

Comment: i think a loop of lambda might work in this case, please assist me with this problem

Comment: @TejasParab, hello! Please, take a look at UPDATE section. This way you can check multiple choices and delete rows based on multiple conditions.

Comment: @TejasParab, glad to help! If this answer is helpfull, you can make it as accepted answer.